# accessing a "Database View" in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I create a Database view using a "create view" statement in my onUpgrade Method.I cannot find good enough code sample on how to access a view in Android.Can someone point me to a sample code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you successfully created the `View`, you can "call" it using a simple `SELECT`-statement like you would query a normal database table.